# How to use async/await pattern with gRPC Web?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, async-await, grpc, grpc-web

I'm developing a Vue.js web application and I'm using gRPC to assure the communication.

In the frontend, I'm using the web version of gRPC: `grpc-web`.

Everything is working just fine; however, when I'm doing an API call in my store, e.g.:

```
async fetchEcho() {
    const echoService = new EchoServiceClient('http://localhost:8080', null, null);

    const request = new EchoRequest();
    request.setMessage('Hello World!');

    const call = echoService.echo(request, {'custom-header-1': 'value1'},
      (err: grpcWeb.Error, response: EchoResponse) => {
        console.log(response.getMessage());
    });
}
```

How can I use the `async/await` pattern when making the call in my Vue file, e.g.:

```
await fetchEcho();
// ...
```

And await until the API call has finished to resume my the course of my program?

Thanks!

Comment: `await` is used with promises. Is there a form of `echo` that returns a promise instead of calling a callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using ServicePromiseClient, the example would be something like this:

```
const echoServiceClient = new EchoServicePromiseClient("http://localhost:8080", null, null);
```

Then I'm able to create async functions for fetching like this:

```
async function fetchEcho() {
    const echoReq = new EchoRequest();
    echoReq.setMessage("Hello world!");
    try {
        const response = await echoServiceClient.echo(echoReq, {});
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's EchoServicePromiseClient (?)  @dmaixner

Comment: @MarlonLópez alternative (promise) client, based on this tutorial: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web#3-write-your-js-client

Answer (score 1):

The *PromiseClinet seems not to be generated anymore. In lieu of that there is a method with a signature that returns a promise

```
 search(
    request: microservice_1_test_pb.SearchRequest,
    metadata: grpcWeb.Metadata | null): Promise<microservice_1_test_pb.SearchResponse>;

  search(
    request: microservice_1_test_pb.SearchRequest,
    metadata: grpcWeb.Metadata | null,
    callback: (err: grpcWeb.RpcError,
               response: microservice_1_test_pb.SearchResponse) => void): grpcWeb.ClientReadableStream<microservice_1_test_pb.SearchResponse>;
```

Using the first

```
    try {
      let response = await this.searchService.search(searchRequest, {})
      this.responseData.data = response.getSearchResponse()

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Got error from server: grpcWeb.RpcError).message-->", (error as grpcWeb.RpcError).message)
      this.responseData.error = (error as grpcWeb.RpcError)

    }
```